# ModuleNotFoundError when building and running dockerfile

Tags: python, dockerfile, tornado

I am trying to build a dockerfile with Poetry.
This is my current file structure:

```
├── backend_services
│   ├── geocoding
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── application
│   │   ├── Domain
│   │   ├── Infrastructure
│   │   │   ├── rest_api
│   │   │   │    ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   │    ├── app.py
│   │   │   │    ├── tornado_api.py      
├── pyproject.toml
├── poetry.lock
└── dockerfile
```

And my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.11

RUN mkdir app

WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml .

RUN pip3 install poetry \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-interaction

RUN poetry --version
RUN mkdir geocoding
COPY geocoding /app/geocoding
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "geocoding/infrastructure/rest_api/app.py"]
```

I have tried different ways to run the file `app.py` file but everytime I try, I get the same error:

```
 File "/app/geocoding/infrastructure/rest_api/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2023-12-05T14:39:32.158715590Z     from geocoding.infrastructure.rest_api.tornado_api import GeocodeHandler
2023-12-05T14:39:32.158719545Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocoding'
```

This error also is shown when I run the app.py through the terminal but not through PyCharm.

Any ideas of why this error shows everytime?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say the problem is that your `geocoding` folder does not contain a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: I will edit the post as I forgot to add the file (it does exist)

Comment: make a main.py in the backend_service filder same level as geolocation and then in main.py import app and run your appllication from there

Comment: @sahasrara62 after doing this it is working locally but when building the dockerfile I still have the same issue

Comment: I guess you missing path when copy folder `COPY geocoding /app/geocoding` instead of `COPY backend_services/geocoding /app/geocoding`